# curl can get web content hosted in local docker but browser cannot open the page

Tags: macos, curl, dns, docker

I installed docker in my mac and have a laravel container running. after pointing the port using docker -p I am successfully getting the web content using cURL. However I am not able to use safari or any other browser to view the page. the url is looking like this: http://191.168.99.100 and I am sure the port is successfully paired between docker and container.

I am wondering if there is a specific troubleshooting method to find the reason of the issue.

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information that this to help. What curl command? From where was the curl command run? Are you sure you have the IP address correct (you list 191.168.99.100 but 192.168.99.100 is more likely for Docker Machine)? Can you ping the IP from your Mac? What was the Docker command you started the container with? Is there any firewall run on your Mac (Systems Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall)?